# What is the maximum capacity of MongoDB? Is it a fully scalable DB?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wish to use MongoDB in one of my projects created with asp.net and c#. What is the maximum capacity of MongoDB? Is it a fully scalable DB? Also wish to know about achieving replication using sharding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes MongoDB is fully *scalable*.

They have a laundry list of deployments over at [MongoDB Production Deployments](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Production+Deployments). MongoDB is trusted with some of the biggest of the "big data" web 2.0 sites such as foursquare, etc, etc. To give an example:

> Wordnik stores its entire text corpus in MongoDB - 1.2TB of data in over 5 billion records.

However, when you get to *sharding* you will want to ensure you don't run your nodes at close to capacity (see: [MongoDB CTO on Foursquare’s Scaling Issues](http://mashable.com/2010/10/07/mongodb-foursquare/))

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and links

Comment: You are very welcome... I would be interested to hear more about your intended application for MongoDB. Perhaps myself or other SO users would be able to give you the comparative pros/cons of using MongoDB over other document-oriented stores. There is one other limitation I forgot to mention, you will want to use a 64bit OS if you are using MongoDB for files over 2Gb (http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, MongoDB is designed from the ground up to be a scalable database.  You can split your data across several hardware nodes, known as [sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Introduction), which is great for scaling both reads and writes.

You can also keep synchronised copies of your data across different nodes, known as [replica sets](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Replica+Sets), which is good for scaling reads and providing failover.

Scalable production deployments use a combination of both.  A great resource for learning more about MongoDB scaling is this book, [Scaling MongoDB](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920018308.do) by Kristina Chodorow